# Print text lines in tree structure using sed

Tags: sed

Lets say I have text like this:

```
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
1. Row1 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
1.1 Row 2 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
1.1.1 Row 3 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
```

the numbers on the begining of lines can consist only "1" with dot and it can go to multiple levels "1.1.1.1.1" etc.
and I want using sed command target those lines with numbers and print them in three structure without those numbers so the result would be:

```
Row1 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
  Row 2 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
    Row 3 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
```

I tried this command `sed -rn 's/1.|1.1|1.1.1/'$'\t/p' Book2.txt` but this doesnt print it in tree structure. I can use only **sed** command.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Thanks for showing what you have already tried. This does not happen so often.

Comment: Is a [tag:sed] combined with [tag:grep] acceptable?

Comment: does the first row of interest start with `1.` or `1` ?

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/^1\./{:a;s/^(\s*)1\.?/\1  /;ta;s/  //p}' file
```

Replace lines beginning `1.` with 2 spaces for each `1.` or a single `1`, then reduce the indent by 2 spaces and print the result.

The 2 spaces can be replaced by `\t` if tabs are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. In case you are ok with `awk`, adding for future users also in case anyone wants to refer `awk` command for this kind of task.

```
awk '
match($0,/^([0-9]+\.){1,}[0-9]+? /){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  printf("%"count1++"s%s\n",(++count>1?" ":""),substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH))
  val=""
}
' Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Row1 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
 Row 2 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
  Row 3 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
```

Comment: **I can use only sed command.**; gives a [tag:awk] solution....

Comment: @0stone0, sure, thank you for letting know. I have added a statement in case anyone else wants to use they could use it, thank you.

Comment: I get downvote on an answer because its not `sed`, can't believe it. That also with no comments. Can't we add answers of tools which are similar, I see people give answers for perl in awk,sed :)

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes find it easier to take these things one step at a time with `sed`, especially if the rules are complicated.

Also - you have a few syntax errors in your command:

```sh
sed -rn 's/1.|1.1|1.1.1/'$'\t/p'
```

The `.` character is a wildcard in `sed`, so you should escape it as `\.` to match the literal. Not sure why there is a `'$'` in there, as well.

Here is a stepped approach:

```sh
sed -n -e '/^1/p' Book2.txt | \
sed -e 's/^1\.\s//' \
    -e 's/^1\.1\s/\t/' \
    -e 's/^1\.1\.1\s/\t\t/'
```

- The first `sed` command removes all the lines from `Book2.txt` that do not begin with 1 and pipes the result to the next command.
- the second `sed` command has 3 parts - each matching the condition of your levels - replacing the matches with appropriate tabs.

Here is the result:

```
Row1 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
    Row 2 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
        Row 3 Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
```

Comment: If I run this, I still get the '1.', '1.1' and '1.1.1' on each line.

Comment: @0stone0 - if both `sed` command are piped, the 1's will be removed.